# Video upload “Only 30 second video will upload”

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with Ap.net C#. I want to find a way to upload a maximum of 30 second duration video clips on upload. if it is vieo long duration
video with 1 GB and i want only 30 second clip upload
Please suggest us.

Comment: Obviously you will need to reduce the size of the video file that you wish to upload. Please give an example of the code that you have tried, as it stands your question is too generic and does not relate to a specific problem to which a simple answer can be given.

Comment: I have only image reducer code. video reducer code still searching

Comment: It might exist but I've never heard of that. You'll probably need to figure out how big the file would likely be for 30 seconds and limit uploads to that *size*.

Comment: size of video file limit 1 GB and 30 minute file  to convert into 30 second